# How do get the Firebase getcurrentuser() into a button or editTextview?

Tags: java, android

Hello I am basically trying to get the mAuth.getCurrentUser() or any of authitcation data from firebase into the textview/button. Android studio whenver I try to insert anything from firebase it needs to be turned into string however, the object/value you get from getCurrentUsers() alternativly I am wondering how you can get email. From the SignInWithEmailAndPassword method.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loggetscreen);

        logoutBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        loginText =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.loggedInTextview);
        firstButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
        secondButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.secondButton);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        String welcomeMessage = "WELCOME to the app";
        FirebaseUser user =mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //welcomeMessage = user.getEmail().toString();
        //loginText.getText(welcomeMessage);

        firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginText.setText("hi "+ welcomeMessage)
            }
        });


        secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginText.setText("I HAVE CHANGED INTO "+ secondButton.getText());
                firstButton.setText(mAuth.getCurrentUser());

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
   if (user != null) {
       String userEmail = user.getEmail();
       firstButton.setText(userEmail);
   } else {
       // No user is signed in
   }
```

Please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you thanks!

Comment: It worked, but no getDisplayName I am getting a null              String userName= user.getDisplayName();

Comment: Try this !
when ```user != null``` then
do this

```
for (UserInfo userInfo : user.getProviderData()) {
        if (displayName == null && userInfo.getDisplayName() != null) {
            displayName = userInfo.getDisplayName();
        }
    }

```
Let me know if it worked @MikeBroski